# Unexpected xtext parsing error

Tags: xtext

I have create the grammar. But, when I parse following text have the problem. Where I'm wrong?
Regards,
Vladimir

Grammar code.

```
grammar com.idc.xtext.ConfigLang with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate configLang "http://www.idc.com/xtext/ConfigLang"

ConfigLangModel hidden(NEW_LINE):
    configItems+=ConfigItem*;

ConfigItem hidden(WS):
    configItemName=VAR_NAME EQUAL configItemValue=VAR_SPECIAL NEW_LINE;

terminal VAR_NAME:
    ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'_'|'-'|':'|INT|'.')+;

terminal VAR_SPECIAL:
    (VAR_NAME|'`'|','|'\\'|'+'|'!'|'^'|'<%' VAR_NAME '>'|';') (VAR_NAME|'`'|','|'\\'|'*'|'+'|'!'|'^'|'<%' VAR_NAME '>'|';')*;

terminal SL_COMMENT: '#' !('\n'|'\r')* ('\r'? '\n')?;

terminal NEW_LINE:('\n'|'\r\n')+;

terminal EQUAL:'=';

terminal ID:
    ANY_OTHER; // Hide the default definition
```

DSL code

```
# $Id: BACKFILL_FIX_MARKETDATA_PORT.config 199954 2015-05-26 16:04:10Z spollard $
MaxMemoryMegs=20480
Dist=idc_apps_full_20150520_199490.jar
```

Errors message

> mismatched input '20480' expecting RULE_VAR_SPECIAL - mismatched input
>   '\n' expecting   RULE_EQUAL

Answer (score 0):

The documentation about [Terminal Rules](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/301_grammarlanguage.html#terminal-rules) tell you:

> Note that the order of terminal rules is crucial for your grammar, as they may shadow each other. This is especially important for newly introduced rules in connection with imported rules from used grammars.

So your terminal rule for `VAR_SPECIAL` is **effectively** this:

```
terminal VAR_SPECIAL:
    ('`'|','|'\\'|'+'|'!'|'^'|'<%' VAR_NAME '>'|';') ('`'|','|'\\'|'*'|'+'|'!'|'^'|'<%' VAR_NAME '>'|';')*;
```

And `20480` ist detected as a `VAR_NAME` due to the `INT` part.

This text would parse but nothing with a "plain" `VAR_NAME`:

```
MaxMemoryMegs=<%20480>
```

Therefore the documentation continues with:

> It’s almost in any case recommended to use data type rules instead. Let’s assume you want to add a rule to allow fully qualified names in addition to simple IDs. Since a qualified name with only one segment looks like a plain ID, you should implement it as a data type rule instead of adding another terminal rule. The same rule of thumb applies to floating point literals, too.

So I guess you should refactor your grammar to use "normal" rules instead of terminal rules.

Besides of this I think you should split up both `VAR_NAME` and `VAR_SPECIAL` - they look suspiciously like some kind of expressions. Or is something like `-:-42` really a valid *name*? Dito for the value.